# want to make circular pie chart shape like buttons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Following are the screenshots of the Ui of Buttons which I want to make using Flutter.

There are the packages [Pie chart](https://pub.dev/packages/pie_chart) and [Syncfusion's package](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/circular-charts/chart-types/pie-chart), but these are different for this approach.

Help me to create these.

[image: Picture 1] [image: Picture 2] [image: picture 3]

Comment: CustomPaint /ClipPath may help

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Yes, but only the packages mentioned in the question.

Comment: Did you find solution for the problem? @DholaSain

Comment: @dijkstra Yes, I've done this.

Comment: @DholaSain could you tell me how you have done?

Comment: @dijkstra I've added the complete code as an answer.

Comment: Thank you  I voted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my solution and now adding on the request of @dijkstra

I've used **PieChart** widget to implement it.

First of all, create a model class

```html
class PieButtonModel {
  PieButtonModel({this.title, required this.onPressed});
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final String? title;
}
```

Now, create a stateless class for Ui. I've used two **PieChart** widgets in stack to match the required output.

```html
class PieButtonScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  PieButtonScreen({Key? key, required this.buttonsData, this.startsFrom}) : super(key: key);
  final List<PieButtonModel> buttonsData;
  final double? startsFrom;
  int touchedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, stateful) {
        return Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: kGreyColor,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Color(0xff1143A7),
                    Color(0xff00B6FE),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: kWhiteColor,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
            ),
            PieChart(
              PieChartData(
                  pieTouchData: PieTouchData(touchCallback: (FlTouchEvent event, pieTouchResponse) {
                    stateful(() {
                      if (!event.isInterestedForInteractions ||
                          pieTouchResponse == null ||
                          pieTouchResponse.touchedSection == null) {
                        touchedIndex = -1;
                        return;
                      }
                      touchedIndex = pieTouchResponse.touchedSection!.touchedSectionIndex;
                      pieButtonPressed(touchedIndex, buttonsData);
                    });
                  }),
                  borderData: FlBorderData(
                      show: true,
                      border: const Border(
                        top: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                      )),
                  sectionsSpace: 5,
                  centerSpaceRadius: 60,
                  centerSpaceColor: const Color(0xFFe7e8e9),
                  startDegreeOffset: startsFrom ?? 0,
                  sections: showingSections()),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.find<ValveViewController>().removeView();
                    },
                    child: Neumorphic(
                      style: const NeumorphicStyle(
                          boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.circle(),
                          color: kWhiteColor,
                          border: NeumorphicBorder(
                            color: Color(0xFF919192),
                            width: 2,
                          )),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 90,
                        width: 90,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          // shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                        ),
                        child: const CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/icon.jpg'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
  }
```

And then, create a list of sections

```html
  List<PieChartSectionData> showingSections() {
    return List.generate(buttonsData.length, (i) {
      PieButtonModel pbm = buttonsData[i];
      final isTouched = i == touchedIndex;
      final fontSize = isTouched ? 14.0 : 11.0;
      final radius = isTouched ? 100.0 : 90.0;
      var val = buttonsData.length / 100;
      List<String>? title = pbm.title?.replaceAll('/ ', '').split(" ");
      return PieChartSectionData(
        color: kGreyColor,
        value: val,
        title: title?.isEmpty == true
            ? ""
            : title?.length == 1
                ? title![0]
                : title!.length == 2
                    ? "${title[0]}\n${title[1]}"
                    : title.length == 3
                        ? "${title[0]}\n${title[1]}\n${title[2]}"
                        : "${title[0]}\n${title[1]}\n${title[2]}\n${title[3]}",
        radius: radius,
        titleStyle: TextStyle(
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          fontSize: fontSize,
          color: kBlackColor,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

Here is the output.

[image]